# Evaluating Query() as bool

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

In SQL Alchemy, an instance of a Query class is returned from each session query made.

I tried to evaluate the query like this, expecting it to behave in a similar way to a list:

`if session.query(...).filter_by(...):`

However it always evaluated to true, so I ended up doing this instead:

`if session.query(...).filter_by(...).count():`

Which seems a bit long-winded and incorrect. Is there a better way to check whether a query will return results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

query is necessarily conservative about when it emits SQL, which is why for example it [has no `__len__()` method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/faq.html#query-has-no-len-why-not).

typically if I want to see if a query returns results, I call `.first()`, so that at least the DB only needs to find one row rather than all of them in order to determine a `.count()`.

Comment: So check whether .first() is None would be a better option then?

Comment: is None, yeah.    Though I wouldn't discourage you from running timeit tests against both methods for a variety of queries...

Comment: OK, will do that when things are a bit further down the line and I have a reasonably large data set to test with. Thanks for your help!